# Firebase: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I ma trying to retrieve the values of the object (Driver) I stored in my Firebase realtime database.

```
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDataBaseRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    mDBChild = mDataBaseRef.child(DB_FAMILY_NODE).child(DB_DRIVER_NODE);
    //mDBChild.setValue(driver);

mDBChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // Check if there is no  children database, create it with default values
        if (!snapshot.exists()){
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_NAME).setValue("Meunier");
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_SURNAME).setValue("Toinou");
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_TOTAL_DISTANCE).setValue("0");
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_TOTAL_TIME).setValue("0");
        }
        else {
            driver = snapshot.getValue(Driver.class);
```

My driver class is:

```
public class Driver implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int totalDistanceDriverInMeter;
    private int totalTimeDriverInSec;
    private ArrayList<Mission> historic = new ArrayList<Mission>();
    private static final String TAG = "Driver";

   public Driver (String n, String s, String td, String tt, ArrayList<Mission> h){
        this.name=n;
        this.surname=s;
        this.totalDistanceDriverInMeter=Integer.valueOf(td);
        this.totalTimeDriverInSec=Integer.valueOf(tt);
        this.historic=h;
    }

    public Driver (){
    }
with all setter and geters
```

When `snapshot.getValue(Driver.class)` is called, I have an error Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int. I first though because Firebase handles everything as string but despite the string to int conversion, I am still facing the error. I know something is surely wrong in my Driver constructor, but I can't find

My JSON is :

```
{
  "Meunier" : {
    "Driver1" : {
      "name" : "Meunier",
      "surname" : "Toine",
      "totalDistanceDriverInMeter" : 8352,
      "totalTimeDriverInSec" : 5820
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data that exists in your database at `mDataBaseRef.child(DB_FAMILY_NODE).child(DB_DRIVER_NODE)` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 2):

```
public Driver (String n, String s, String td, String tt, ArrayList<Mission> h){
    this.name=n;
    this.surname=s;
    this.totalDistanceDriverInMeter=Integer.valueOf(td);
    this.totalTimeDriverInSec=Integer.valueOf(tt);
    this.historic=h;
}
```

This constructor has nothing to do with Firebase when you use `snapshot.getValue(Driver.class)`.

Actually `snapshot.getValue(Driver.class)` triggers getters & setters of the fields that exist in Firebase nodes.

So, you can transfer the conversion in the getters & setters as follows:

```
public class Driver implements Parcelable {

    private int totalDistanceDriverInMeter;
    private int totalTimeDriverInSec;

   // ............. rest of code

    public String getTotalDistanceDriverInMeter() {
        return String.valueOf(totalDistanceDriverInMeter);
    }

    public void setTotalDistanceDriverInMeter(String totalDistanceDriverInMeter) {
        this.totalDistanceDriverInMeter = Integer.parseInt(totalDistanceDriverInMeter);
    }

    public String getTotalTimeDriverInSec() {
        return String.valueOf(totalTimeDriverInSec);
    }

    public void setTotalTimeDriverInSec(String totalTimeDriverInSec) {
        this.totalTimeDriverInSec = Integer.parseInt(totalTimeDriverInSec);
    }

    public Driver() {
    }

}
```

This should solve the `Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int` Exception, but I think you use the getters & setters in your app with their integer values... so, this need to be handled; you can either use the same getters & setters, but do the conversion back or you can use create other methods for that.

Comment: @R42136 Glad to hear :) thanks to accept the answer if it solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is (as Zain already pointed out) that you're storing the numbers as string values from your code, but assume that they are numeric when you read them back.

I recommend consistently treating them as numbers, and converting them from/to string only in the places where that is absolutely necessary (such as when showing/reading them from the UI).

So instead of this code:

```
mDBChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // Check if there is no  children database, create it with default values
        if (!snapshot.exists()){
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_NAME).setValue("Meunier");
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_SURNAME).setValue("Toinou");
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_TOTAL_DISTANCE).setValue("0");
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_TOTAL_TIME).setValue("0");
        }
```

Do:

```
mDBChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // Check if there is no  children database, create it with default values
        if (!snapshot.exists()){
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_NAME).setValue("Meunier");
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_SURNAME).setValue("Toinou");
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_TOTAL_DISTANCE).setValue(0);
            mDBChild.child(DB_DRIVER_TOTAL_TIME).setValue(0);
        }
```

Or better, use your own helper class to do the conversion **and** use only a single `setValue` call:

```
mDBChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // Check if there is no  children database, create it with default values
        if (!snapshot.exists()){
            mDBChild.setValue(new Driver("Meunier", "Toinou", "0", "0"))
        }
```